# Session cookie being destroyed before browser is closed

Tags: session, cookies

I use a session cookie to maintain my php sessions and it works just fine for most (99% of users). There is a function my web app that sends the user to an external site. After doing some things on that site, the site will redirect my user back to my page. When they return, they no longer have a session cookie. They can get around this by connecting to the site in a different tab and leaving that tab open while they navigate to the site from the original tab. Again, this is machine specific ... I can't replicate the behavior on my computer unless i manually delete the cookie.

So, it appears that by navigating the current window away from my site the browser is acting as if the browser has closed and re-opened ... it deletes the session cookie for my site.

My question: Is there a browser setting that can be set to remove session cookies when a user navigates away from a page - if so, what is it so i can get them to turn it off ? I assume there is 3rd party software that will do this but would like to know what the setting is called so i can give them direction.

Comment: Could you ask what browser and version they are using? See also if Chrome's Settings->Privacy->Content Settings->Cookies->Block third-party cookies and data replicates the behaviour. Good luck.

Comment: perhaps this question belongs on superuser instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FWIW I did eventually figure this out.
The 3rd party shifting from https://{mydomain}.com to https://{subdomain}.{mydomain}.com when sending the user back to my site. That caused the cookie I used to maintain session to get "lost".